# Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)'

Tags: windows, powershell

I have uninstalled .NET 4.5 and installed 4.0. But now, Powershell is not working. It is opening and closing itself. Below is the error that I am getting. Your suggestions please :-

Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)'

Thanks in Advance !!